# Exclude test class directory for archiving in Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar, build-process

I have created a java library project. The binaries are available at `<project-dir>/bin`. The test classes are available at `<project-dir>/bin/com/myproject/test`. I need to exclude archiving of my test classes. So, I wrote the following code:

```
<target depends="build-all" name="build-dist">
    <jar destfile="app.jar" basedir="bin" excludes="com/myproject/test/*.class" />
</target>
```

This works fine. But in the archive the directory `test` is still available. How to remove this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to keep test Java and class files in different directories. So instead of compiling them into `bin`, compile them in a second step into `bin-test`. This also makes sure that the non-test code can't see test classes (compilation will fail if you accidentally import a test in a production class).

Answer (score 5):

```
<jar destfile="app.jar" basedir="bin" excludes="com/myproject/test/" />
```

Comment: The trailing ** is not needed.  See: http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns 'There is one "shorthand": if a pattern ends with / or \, then ** is appended'.